# Rolling mean in Pandas and insert the mean into the next row of the window

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to insert the rolling mean value to the row below and not in the same row as a window. I could use the shift method to achieve that, however you experts could tip me with much more efficient methods. Thank you!

`df_ts['mittel'] =df_ts['convertedAccx'].rolling(2,min_periods=2).mean()`

[image: Dataframe with actual and expected output.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine !

```
df1:
   a
0  0
1  0
2  1
3  2

data_dic = {
    "a": [0,0,1,2]
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_dic)

print(df1['a'].rolling(2,min_periods=2).mean())

>>>
0    NaN
1    0.0
2    0.5
3    1.5
```

Please add a sample of your dataframe if you are still facing the issue.